# Starting and stopping processes in a cluster

Tags: python, linux, network-programming, cluster-computing

I'm writing software that runs a bunch of different programs (via [twisted's](http://twistedmatrix.com) `twistd`); that is N daemons of various kinds must be started across multiple machines. If I did this manually, I would be running commands like `twistd foo_worker`, `twistd bar_worker` and so on on the machines involved.

**Basically there will be a list of machines, and the daemon(s) I need them to run. Additionally, I need to shut them all down when the need arises.**

If I were to program this from scratch, I would write a "spawner" daemon that would run permanently on each machine in the cluster with the following features accessible through the network for an authenticated administrator client:

- Start a process with a given command line. Return a handle to manage it.
- Kill a process given a handle.
- Optionally, query stuff like cpu time given a handle.

It would be fairly trivial to program the above, but I cannot imagine this is a new problem. Surely there are existing solutions to doing exactly this? I do however lack experience with server administration, and don't even know what the related terms are.

**What existing ways are there to do this on a linux cluster, and what are some of the important terms involved?** Python specific solutions are welcome, but not necessary.

Another way to put it: Given a bunch of machines in a lan, how do I programmatically work with them as a cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most familiar and universal way is just to use `ssh`. To automate you could use [`fabric`](http://fabfile.org).

To start `foo_worker` on all hosts:

```
$ fab all_hosts start:foo_worker
```

To stop `bar_worker` on a particular list of hosts:

```
$ fab -H host1,host2 stop:bar_worker
```

Here's an example `fabfile.py`:

```
from fabric.api import env, run, hide # pip install fabric

def all_hosts():
    env.hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']

def start(daemon):
    run("twistd --pid %s.pid %s" % (daemon, daemon))

def stop(daemon):
    run("kill %s" % getpid(daemon))

def getpid(daemon):
    with hide('stdout'):
        return run("cat %s.pid" % daemon)

def ps(daemon):
    """Get process info for the `daemon`."""
    run("ps --pid %s" % getpid(daemon))
```

[There are a number of ways to configure host lists in fabric, with scopes varying from global to per-task, and it’s possible mix and match as needed.](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/usage/execution.html#defining-host-lists).

To streamline the process management on a particular host you could write initd scripts for the daemons (and run `service daemon_name start/stop/restart`) or use [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org) (and run `supervisorctl` e.g., `supervisorctl stop all`). To control "what installed where" and to push configuration in a centralized manner something like [`puppet`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29) could be used.

Comment: Now that is what I call a high quality answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The usual tool is a batch queue system, such as SLURM, SGE, Torque/Moab, LSF, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Circus :

Documentation :
http://docs.circus.io/en/0.5/index.html

Code:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/circus/0.5

Summary from the documentation :

> Circus is a process & socket manager. It can be used to monitor and control processes and sockets.
>
> Circus can be driven via a command-line interface or programmatically trough its python API.
>
> It shares some of the goals of Supervisord, BluePill and Daemontools. If you are curious about what Circus brings compared to other projects, read Why should I use Circus instead of X ?.
>
> Circus is designed using ZeroMQ http://www.zeromq.org/. See Design for more details.